# How to create a Solr collection that doesn't shuffle the createNodeSet hosts using the SolrJ API?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm trying to create a Solr collection on SolrCloud, and I want to pass in the hosts I want the collection to exist on in a certain order, and have Solr follow that order. Solr exposes this functionality in the API with the parameter `createNodeSet.shuffle`, but I can't explicitly set this parameter in a `SolrAdminRequest.Create` instance.

Does this functionality not exist within Solrj? Can I set the value with the setProperties() method even though it's a "param"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem too, and I notice that you had opened a PR on the [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/pull/467). I've tried several ways to achieve this goal but finally I give up by shuffling the nodes myself, before passing them to the `Create` request.

In `Kotlin`:

```
val nodes = listOf("node1", "node2")
val createNodeSet = nodes.shuffled().joinToString(",")
```

In `Java`:

```
List<String> nodes = Arrays.asList("node1", "node2");
Collections.shuffle(nodes);
String createNodeSet = String.join(",", nodes);
```

Comment: Yeah, just waiting for that PR to be reviewed... But actually, the Solr docs state that the CreateNodeSet.shuffle param defaults to `true`. If you pass in a CreateNodeSet, Solr should shuffle them automatically. I ran into my issue because I wanted to turn this functionality _off_.

Comment: Now I ran into my issue and I want to turn this functionality off too, so sad. @Benedict have you figured out how to do this before the Pull Request is merged?

Comment: I ended up extending the create collection operation class and overloaded the getParams() method to finesse in the `createNodeSet.shuffle=false` that I wanted. It's not pretty but it got the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

As current Solr now has the constructor marked as protected, only accessible via a static builder, and as I didn't want to have a new class to worry about, I figured out the following way to set the needed parameter.

This method should be usable on many of the other builder created op objects.

```java
Create req = CollectionAdminRequest //
                            .createCollection(newCollection, newConfigSet, NUM_SHARDS, NUM_REPLICAS);
final SolrParams reqParams = req.getParams();
if (reqParams instanceof ModifiableSolrParams) {
    ((ModifiableSolrParams) reqParams).set("createNodeSet.shuffle", "false");
}
```